# BufferedReader object works for 2.3.3 and jelly bean but not 4.0.4

Tags: android, bufferedreader

I have no problem running my app in Gingerbread and Jelly Bean, but I get errors when running on Honeycomb. Here is the following piece of code that creates errors:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            url.openStream()));
```

Where url is a URL object that references text on a public website. After that I call the following lines of code to extract the text:

```
String inputLine;
String message = "";
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        message = message + inputLine;
in.close();
```

It doesn't get past the BufferedReader line of code though. Once that line of code is invoked I get the following errors:

```
04-16 08:36:50.750: W/System.err(5051): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-16 08:36:50.750: W/System.err(5051):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1119)
04-16 08:36:50.750: W/System.err(5051):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:441)
04-16 08:36:50.750: W/System.err(5051):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:243)
04-16 08:36:50.750: W/System.err(5051):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
04-16 08:36:50.758: W/System.err(5051):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
04-16 08:36:50.758: W/System.err(5051):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
04-16 08:36:50.758: W/System.err(5051):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
04-16 08:36:50.758: W/System.err(5051):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
04-16 08:36:50.758: W/System.err(5051):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
04-16 08:36:50.758: W/System.err(5051):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
04-16 08:36:50.758: W/System.err(5051):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:460)
04-16 08:36:50.758: W/System.err(5051):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:432)
04-16 08:36:50.758: W/System.err(5051):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
04-16 08:36:50.766: W/System.err(5051):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
04-16 08:36:50.766: W/System.err(5051):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
04-16 08:36:50.766: W/System.err(5051):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
04-16 08:36:50.766: W/System.err(5051):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:270)
04-16 08:36:50.766: W/System.err(5051):     at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)
04-16 08:36:50.766: W/System.err(5051):     at com.hasta.upark.Data.getOccupancy(Data.java:39)
04-16 08:36:50.774: W/System.err(5051):     at com.hasta.upark.MapsActivity.updateMarker(MapsActivity.java:362)
04-16 08:36:50.774: W/System.err(5051):     at com.hasta.upark.MapsActivity$2.run(MapsActivity.java:159)
04-16 08:36:50.774: W/System.err(5051):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-16 08:36:50.774: W/System.err(5051):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-16 08:36:50.774: W/System.err(5051):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-16 08:36:50.774: W/System.err(5051):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4697)
04-16 08:36:50.774: W/System.err(5051):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 08:36:50.774: W/System.err(5051):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-16 08:36:50.774: W/System.err(5051):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
04-16 08:36:50.774: W/System.err(5051):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
04-16 08:36:50.774: W/System.err(5051):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: are you doing this on the main thread?

Comment: No, this is a background thread that updates every period of seconds

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: See the edit above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top line of your error: `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`... It isn't happening on a background thread like you think. Double check that.

Once you properly get it set up and running on a background thread (I suggest using AsyncTask to simplify the process) the error should go away.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html this got the job done thanks!

Comment: If you run it on the main thread it should crash in jelly bean.